# Filter/ Remove rows of value that dates fall on 2021 from given dataframe

Tags: python

Filter and remove dates that fall on 2021 from the given dataframe.

Example:

```py
MNG     Cus         Regis_date
8059    281614530   20211230
8099    2810288123  20211105
8099    2810288123  20211106
8099    2810288123  20211210
8099    2810288123  20220110
8099    2810288123  20220124
8960    2815496326  20220422
```

Desired output:

```
MNG     Cus         Regis_date
8960    2815496326  20220422
```

Please help!
Thanks!

[table photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnJeG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# list to store unique cus
cus: list = []

# Filter cus that have regis_date in 2021
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Cus'] not in cus and row['Regis_date'].year == 2021:
        cus.append(row['Cus'])

# Remove cus that have regis_date in 2021
df = df[df['Cus'].isin(cus) == False]
```

Comment: This removes 2021 Rows but with Cus (2810288123) has Regis date 2021 and 2022. I hope that can remove entire Cus rows that just include 1 year 2021.

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to remove the customer if any of his Regis date falls in 2021. correct?

Comment: Can you help me to filter year 2021? Example: 20220124 is string, i can use function year to filter 2022! | and row['Regis_date'].year == 2021: